# Consider defining a bean of type '(@Service classpath)' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm attempting to use Spring MVC to create a web application. In this application (which is a project in IntelliJ), I have a `@Controller` with three `@Service`s that are to be `@Autowired`. I'm also using Spring DevTools to speed up development, but it's also the source of this problem.

I won't include my actual code here (as it would be too long), but below are a couple of dummy `@Service`s that are similar in structure to my own `@Service` classes.

Service1.java

```java
// package & imports

public interface Service1 {
    void foo();

    // lots of other methods
}
```

Service1Impl.java

```java
// package & imports

@Slf4j
@Service
public class Service1Impl implements Service1 {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        log.info("Foo!");
    }

    // lots of other code
}
```

Service2.java

```java
// package & imports

public interface Service2 {
    void bar();

    // lots of other methods
}
```

Service2Impl.java

```java
// package & imports

@Slf4j
@Service
public class Service2Impl implements Service2 {
    @Override
    public void bar() {
        log.info("bar!");
    }

    // lots of other code
}
```

And so on. My `@Controller` class has dependencies of both of these `@Service`s, which are injected through `@Autowired.`

SiteController.java

```java
// package & imports

@Slf4j // not used but is there in my code
@Controller
public class SiteController {
    private final Service1 service1;
    private final Service2 service2;

    @Autowired
    public SiteController(Service1 one, Service2 two) {
        service1 = one;
        service2 = two;
    }

    @ResponseBody // just for simplicity's sake
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        service1.foo();
        service2.bar();

        return "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\" /></head><body>Hello, there!</body></html>";
    }
}
```

Starting up the application works just fine. However, when I rebuild the project in IntelliJ, Spring DevTools occasionally gives me an error in the console similar to the one below after attempting to restart the application:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in (@Controller classpath) required a bean of type '(@Service classpath)' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type '(@Service classpath)' in your configuration.
```

<del>However, the controller code should be functional. If I change the constructor to this,</del>

```java
public SiteController(@Autowired Service1 one, @Autowired Service2 two) {
    service1 = one;
    service2 = two;
}
```

<del>I can't replicate the error. However, the two different versions of the constructor should be equivalent.</del> The error occurred with this version as well.

What is happening here and is this a bug? I'm absolutely stumped since my code does run correctly for the first time, but after Spring DevTools restarts it, it sometimes crashes.

Comment: does Service2Impl implements Service2 ?

Comment: @MandarDharurkar, yes. Thank you for catching that. See my edits above.

Comment: Hey ! did u add @service to ServiceImpl2 ?

Comment: My guess is that this has to do with a race condition during recompilation (DevTools tries to reload the application, but the `.class` file for your S2 isn't created yet).

Comment: My goodness, why didn't I catch that? Thanks, @MandarDharurkar.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Sounds plausible, but how would I ensure that Spring DevTools restarts only _after_ compilation?

Comment: @LeftistTachyon I use Eclipse!

Comment: @chylis-onstrike- Does Eclipse automatically do that? I still want to use IntelliJ for this project, though

Comment: Hey @LeftistTachyon , can we close this issue ? i can add my comment as answer to this question .

Comment: No, @MandarDharurkar. You haven't answered my question anywhere in your comments.

Comment: @LeftistTachyon, I thought adding service annotation on ServiceImpl2 resolved your issue.

Comment: No, that was just a typo

Comment: As I said, these are just examples and not my actual code.